# Determining distance between polygons in two shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, distance, proximity

I have a parcel shp and a lake shp.

How to calculate the distance between the parcel polygon and the lake?

I do not want to use the measure ruler tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: Use near analysis, it will populate parcels table with near_dist.

Comment: You can use [Generate Near Analysis](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) because it calculate all the distances not just the closest feature

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Generate Near Table](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm), which will use FIDs to relate your two polygons. e.g. parcel_poly can be the IN_FID and lake_poly can be the OUT_FID, or vice versa. I believe the general Near tool would also work, but the output will not be a standalone table.